# Como inicializar una variable de tipo Date en PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, null

tengo una procedimiento en Oracle, para validar si las 2 fechas de una determina tabla es mayor o no. Lo que pasa es que cuando lo inicializo mis variables vFechaA y vFechaB en NULL, no se porque considera que la fecha mayor es NULL y no la Fecha que tiene data, porque puede pasar que una de las tablas llegue vacio la variable. Como haria la validacion ?

```
Procedure NombreProcedure(parm1 Out Varchar2)is
vFechaA Date := NULL;
vFechaB Date := NULL;
Begin
   Begin
     Select FECHA_A
     Into vFechaA
     From Tabla_A
   End;
   Begin
     Select FECHA_B
     Into vFechaB
     From Tabla_B
   End;
   
   If vFechaA > vFechaB Then
      parm1 := 'vFechaA es Mayor';
   Else
      parm1 := 'vFechaB es Mayor';
   EndIf;
End;
```

Este seria el siguiente caso:

FechaA = 04/07/13 y FechaB = Null(No encontro fecha en la tabla_B)

**El Resultado que espero,** es tomar la FechaA como mayor ya que la FechaB es Nulo.

**El Resultado que obtengo,** como la fechaB es Nulo, lo considera como mayor en vez de tomar la FechaA.

Imprime:
vFechaB es Mayor

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y escribir el resultado esperado y el obtenido? Además, ¿qué sucede si ambas fechas son NULL?

Comment: La respuesta básica es: qué quieres que pase? Es decir, quien conoce el modelo de datos, las tablas y los posibles valores de esas columnas eres tú (y no están en la pregunta), así que es tu responsabilidad considerar ese caso en tu procedimiento y añadirlo a tus validaciones. Lo único que podemos confirmar es que, si el select no encuentra datos a traer, la variable seguirá nula (no hay dato a almacenar).

Comment: La fecha de hoy ¿es mayor que null o es menor que null? Depende si consideras que null equivale al inicio de los tiempos o al fin de los tiempos -u otro momento incluso-; las bases de datos no definen tal criterio, por lo cual el resultado de la comparación se considera *Indefinida* (ni verdadera ni falsa) y al no ser verdadera cae en el `Else`.

Answer (score 0):

Valida los casos nulos. Y ya está

```
Procedure NombreProcedure(parm1 Out Varchar2) is
    vFechaA Date := NULL;
    vFechaB Date := NULL;
Begin
   Begin
     Select FECHA_A
     Into vFechaA
     From Tabla_A
   End;
   Begin
     Select FECHA_B
     Into vFechaB
     From Tabla_B
   End;
   
   IF vFechaA IS NULL THEN
      parm1 := 'vFechaB es mayor';
   ELSIF vFechaB IS NULL OR vFechaA > vFechaB Then
      parm1 := 'vFechaA es Mayor';
   ELSE
      parm1 := 'vFechaB es Mayor';
   EndIf;
End;
```

Lo otro: para qué necesitas bloques de transacción rodeando cada select? Si modificaran datos se entendería (de alguna forma) que crearas bloques de transaccción, pero en este caso... para qué?